# Local Host redirected you too many times Issue with IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2022, iis-10, windows-11

I am working on bringing a working web application onto a new computer running Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.2 and .NET Framework 4.7.2. When running on local IIS (version 10.0) host there is a "local host redirected you too many times" issue. It suggests clearing cookies which has been done with no effect.
The same code works on other machines with no issues. Is there anything in IIS set up/configuration or that may be missing from Visual Studio or other installations? Thanks in advance.

So far we have tried debugging the code and including breakpoints for where the issue may be occurring, ensuring that the installations of windows feature and IIS management is the same as another where the program is working. Also created a .txt file that can be reached on local host and is in same location as the rest of the project.

Comment: Use the browser's developer tools to see what are the 30x redirection responses and that can get you started on finding the source and resolve the issue. Don't expect others to help much as none of us can touch your machine remotely.

Comment: You can also track the cause by generating logs through [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing). After all your web application can work on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try:

- Try on another machine.
- Try to remove as much rules as possible from web.config and keys and so on. Or if it's a single page you're having the error with try to remove as much code from it especially if there are redirect codes. And add breakpoints and debug.
- Check the LOCAL application pool version if it's set same as the online .net framework version.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have an httpredirect rule in place?  I ran into this when trying to force `https` from the webserver but instead it would just cause an infinite loop:

1. From IIS, navigate to your site and click on `HTTP Redirect`
   [image: HTTP Redirect]
2. Remove the `Redirect requests to this destination` checkbox
   [image: Redirect requests to this destination]
3. Click `Apply` on the right side `Actions` panel
   [image: Actions > Apply]
4. Try your site again.